# Поговорка "не мытьем, так катаньем"

Tags: фразеология

Говорят "не мытьем, так катаньем" в значении "любым способом". Но о чем изначально шла речь?

Comment: Кстати, что именно можно делать "не мытьем, так катаньем"? По-моему, главным образом добиваться чего-то от человека. Вряд ли можно сказать: "Не мытьем, так катаньем выучила тему".
Почему произошел такой переход, если изначально и мыли и катали белье?

Comment: Человек здесь ни при чем. Ключевое слово - добиваться. То ли так, то ли эдак. Менять способы. Вот если вы эту тему сначала в школе слушали, потом дома учили, у библиотеку ходили, репетирору наняли - и все бестолку, а потом вдруг гипнозом или во сне выучили - это самое оно будет.

Comment: Может, и так. Я посмотрела Национальный корпус. Там фразы, относящиеся к человеку (или группе людей) составляют процентом 75. А если развернуть слишком краткие контексты - может и больше.  
Кроме того, Ваш пример нетипичен еще и позитивной направленностью: билась, старалась - и получилось. Но в примерах, скорее, подчеркивается упрямство, изворотливость, нечистоплотность в выборе средств. Часто звучат глаголы _донять, допекать ("доехать"), взять противника, добиться_. И даже при нейтральых глаголах смысл тот же.

Comment: А  мог  бы  изначально  быть  такой  смысл :  если  и  не  выстирать,  то  хоть  выкатать ?

Comment: Много пониманий этой пословицы слышал, про белье про валенки про карты, а вот про тело впервые... Интересная мысль и помоему правдоподобней всех...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О стирке. К**а**танье - процесс очистки белья с помощью специальной ребристой доски. Бельё при этом били и катали по доске, таким образом выбивали или выкатывали все, что не получалось отстирать.
Вроде бы раньше было еще более хирое приспособление для той же цели, там это "выкатывание" грязи было еще более наглядным, но тут я наверняка не знаю.

Comment: Бельё  при  этом  не  били.

Comment: Бегемотус,  может  вы  "стиральную  доску"  вспомнили.  В  кавычках  потому,  что  она  делась  и  оцинкованного  железа.  По  этому  приспособлению  бельё  можно  бить,  но  в  основном  тёрли.  Но  не  катали !

Answer (score 3):

Бельё, одежду или ткань накручивали на скалку, держа одной рукой, а сверху другой рукой катали рубель. Бельё разглаживалось, и называлось это «катать бельё».

Comment: Это все так, но это процедура глажки, к мытью не имеет отношения.

Comment: Нигде не нашел, что прокатыванием (именно так называлось дейстивие со скалкой и рубелем) как-то устранялись дефекты "мытья". Хотя сам по себе, конечно, факт стОящий внимяния.

Comment: Наверное, имелось в виду: не постирал, так хоть поглажу:)

Comment: >Наверное, имелось в виду: не постирал, так хоть поглажу:) 
  
Ну если имеется в виду буквальное понимание, то - да, значения слов допускают и такое толкование. Но что могла такая фраза значить в переносном смысле? 
Разве вшей вывести... Кстати да! Это бы объясняло современное употребление.

Comment: Не  по  делу  для  Инны :  скалку ( она  называлось -  валёк ) после  того,  как  на  него  намотали   бельё,  рукой  не  придерживали.  Рубелем  нужно  было  управляться  двумя  руками.  Одной  рукой  рубель  держали  за  ручку,  а  другой  прижимали  рубель  к  вальку.

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл  в  сети  другое  толкование,  в  котором  мытьё  производят  от  мыто ( налог ),  катанье  от  кат ( палач ).  Смысл - не  отдашь  мытарю  добровольно,  отдашь  после  наказания.

Comment: Оба значения весьма вольно поданы. Хотя для этих значений указанный смысл не просматривается.

Но дело даже не в этом. Как мыт мог стать мытьем,и а как - катаньем?

Comment: Не  знаю.  Нигде  в  текстах,  описывающих  такие  методы,  я  таких  слов  не  встречал,  но  и  специально  не  искал  в  словарях.  Но,  в  принципе,  мытьё  (  процесс  сбора  налогов ) могло  образоваться  по  шаблону  битьё,  и  с  кАтаньем  -  так  же.

Answer (score 2):

Эта поговорка из среды карточных игроков. **Мытая** игра – это **чистая,** честная игра, а **катать**, значит играть, применяя некоторые специальные приёмы(**прокатывать** карту между пальцами, перекатывать карту с верхней части колоды в нижнюю и т.д.), отсюда **катала**.

> Не мытьём, так катаньем

, - не получится честная победа, возьмём хитростью. Не понимаю, почему здесь все ухватились за идею с бельём. Если кто-то сочтёт мой ответ неправильным, объясните, пожалуйста, происхождение слова "катала", в значении "карточный шулер"?

Comment: раньше было три наперстка, стакана, и катали между ними шарик. Простенько. Потом народ стал образованным и появились карты, а три листка--как фокус остались. развод идет по пути усложнения. Растет профессионализм. Метод неизменен.

Answer (score 0):

Всё на много проще и без всякого скрытого смысла. 
Речь изначально была об очищении от грязи, но не белья, а тела. 
Имелось в виду два способа. 
Один: нормальный, правильный, общепринятый - помыться.
Другой: когда нет другого выхода или для ленивых, в общем "хоть как то" - катая грязь (потирая ладонью грязную часть тела. Скатывая грязь в катышки.)

Comment: Увасоригинальнаямысль только та, что речь идет о теле. Но это совершенно (a) не подтверждается  аргументацией, (б) идет вразрез с понианием - более слабый "способ" вдруг становится более действенным. .