# Какая версия происхождения фразеологизма "не мытьём, так катаньем" наиболее вероятна?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

В Интернете рассматриваются три основные (наиболее частотные) версии фразеологизма, например:

http://chtooznachaet.ru/vyrazhenie_ne_mytem_tak_kataniem.html

https://www.esperanto-plus.ru/fraz/n/ne-mitjem.htm

Версия про мытарей и палачей мне кажется **единственно верной,** так как только в ней четко выражено **ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЕ:** если не получится одним способом, то используем другой. В двух других версиях эти процессы скорее **дополняют** друг друга, но уж никак не противопоставлены, а именно эта мысль и является **главной**. **По смыслу** валенки вообще не годятся (там **соединительные** отношения), а белье прокатывали, чтобы погладить, а не чтобы постирать.

А вы как считаете? Существуют ли какие-то **исследования или авторитетные мнения** на эту тему? Спасибо.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

А также меня заинтересовал такой вопрос: каково происхождение трех названных версий этого фразеологизма. **Их высказали конкретные лингвисты-этимологи, можем ли мы назвать автора каждой из этих версий?** А вдруг это всего лишь **народная этимология**, как тогда можно доверять такой информации?

В предыдущем обсуждении этой темы, да и в различных публикациях в Интернете почему-то не принято **указывать источники**, мне же теперь это кажется очень **важным и необходимым.**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поговорка "не мытьем, так катаньем"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8293/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: Извините, но япротив удаления моих возражений по существу версии про мытаря.  Вынужден их повторить вкратце. "Мытье" и "катанье" могло произойти только от глаголов "мыть" и "катать", каковые глаголы не годятся в качестве производящих, поскольку сами образованы (в вашей версии) от существительных. К тому же они не имеют подходящих значений. Ваша версия была бы правдоподобной для вариант "не мытарем, но катом", но такой не зафиксировано.

Comment: Вроде бы не было комментариев, они в другом вопросе

Comment: Это в каком "другом"? Писал-то я здесь, насколько помню. И писал их именно вам.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461881/Каково-значение-поговорки-Не-мытьЁм-так-кАтаньем

Comment: А, понятно... Но тот-то вопрос закрыли, так что по сути я не сильно ошибся. А смысла переливать из пустого в порожнее я не вижу. Мнение мое от того, что вопрос таким хитрым способом переоткрыт, не изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

Нужную информацию можно найти в историко-этимологическом справочнике "Словарь русской фразеологии" (А.К. Бирих, В.М. Мокиенко, Л.И. Степанова). Там приводится две версии.

По основной версии это исконно русское выражение возникло изначально в речи прачек, поскольку хорошо прокатанное бельё имело отличный вид, даже если качество стирки было не очень. Не понимаю, почему сложно заметить, о каком противопоставлении идёт речь.

По другой версии оборот мог родиться в среде валенщиков-шерстобитов.

Список источников в пользу первой версии намного шире.

Для придумывания собственных версий необходимо проводить хотя бы поверхностный анализ: когда появился фразеологизм, как часто за отказ платить пошлину за проезд или провоз товара (мытом называли именно такую пошлину, а не любой налог) человека отправляли к палачу? Наверное, часто, раз это вошло в народную поговорку. А купцы, не заплатившие мыто и идущие из-за этого на казнь, должны были выглядеть героями в глазах народа, если я правильно понимаю. И всё это не вызывает ни тени сомнений?

Хорошо ещё, что любителям неизвестно другое древнее значение слова **мыто** — понос.

**Добавление** по дополнительно возникшим вопросам.

Приведу список авторов, которые приводили разные версии:
**Версия 1:**
Вартаньян Э.А.
Вакуров В.Н.
Гвоздарёв Ю.А.
Шанский Н.М., Зимин В.И., Филиппов А.В. (в соавторстве, в разных изданиях)

**Версия 2**:
Разумов А.А.
Вартаньян Э.А.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос задан так расплывчато, что он позволяет написать ответ на любую затронутую тему.

Так вот я хочу еще раз повторить возражения против версии "мытаря и ката".
~1. Мало того, что сама по себе идея, что чего-то можно добиться таким образом (если не таможенником, то палачом) довольно странная, так она еще непонятно кого предполагает в качестве носителя подобного менталитета. Власть предержащая явно не заинтересована в подобной характеристике своих методов управления, а больше-то и некому.  Это, впрочем, несколько субъективно, но если бы это возражение было единственным...
~2. Для оправдания подобной версии изобретаются слова "катанье" и "мытьё" в неизвестных ранее значениях, то есть факты искусственно подгоняются под версию. При этом совершенно игнорируется то, что нужды в таких словах просто нет. Если мытье связано с мытоом, то на это есть понятное мытарь, равно как и собсвтвенно "кат". Поговорка в виде "Не мытарем, но катом" была бы куда понятнее и естественнее.
~3. Игнорируется и то, что мытье и катанье - по форме отглаглдльные образования (от мыть и катать), от существительных мыт(о) и кат такое просто невозможно. Но "мыть" и "катать" не зафиксированы в подобных значениях. Есть, правда диалектное "катовать", но это суффиксальное образование явно более позднего времени. Или вообще заимствование из украинского, где имеет другое значение.

Короче, в этой версии сплошные натяжки.

Что же имеют возразить апологеты легенды про "мытаря и ката" основной (прачечной) версии?
Собственно, у них только два осмысленных возражения.
~1. Смешение (якобы) ударения на первый слок в слове "катанье". Представляется несерьезным, есть слово катка (прокатка) - и соответствующий процесс носит название имеено к**а**тка, к**а**танье.
~2. Использование слова "мытье" (которое в данном значении носит просторечно-разговорный характер) вместо "стирка". Вот тут согласен, сильно смущает. И вот это дает некоторые очки в пользу весии о валенках (шесть именно моют, а не стирают), но у этой версии свои минусы. "Катание шерсти" выглядит еще более искуственным сочетанием, чем даже "мытье шерсти".

Остальное - см. @grizzly.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Мое мнение изменилось в том плане, что я больше не ищу полного семантического и лексического соответствия ни в одной  из названных тем. Семантика мне мыслится обобщенной, а лексика и сама ситуации  в каждой версии подходят в той или иной мере. Это всего лишь  конкретика для выражения определенной абстрактной идеи.

Answer (score 1):

Следуя поговорке «вода путь найдет», она легко обходит все на своем пути: валуны на перекатах, бобровые запруды.
Почему бы не предположить, что в поговорке «не мытьем, так катаньем» пронырливых, напористых особей сравнивают с водой, смывающей препятствия со своего пути или, при нехватке сил - перекатывающейся через них.

Comment: Спасибо, оригинальное мнение. Оно как раз говорит о возможности многозначного толкования фразеологических оборотов. В конце концов, фразеологизм - это образное народное мышление. Одна и та же форма речи может соответствовать и разным реалиям,  и разным идеям. Какая-то версия была изначальной, но потом ее могли использовать в других ситуациях. И всё это - народное творчество, а вот от толкования этого творчества народ решительно отстраняется.

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю вопрос так.  Это своего рода **иносказание**, которое может быть представлено как темой палач и мытарь, так и другими вариантами тоже.

Но  в действительности  речь идет **о взаимоотношении человека и административных структур,** которые всегда найдут возможность получить желаемое любым способом и всегда смогут доказать свою правоту.
Это своего рода жалоба народа, его мечта о справедливости, которую никак не получается найти. Вероятно, это иносказание можно высказать в разных вариантах, но по большому счету все они выступают только как метафоры.

Поэтому здесь могут быть интересны  конкретные исторические сведения о времени появления фразеологизма, о его понимании современниками. А вот насчет прачек у меня большие сомнения: вряд ли эта  категории тружеников  была способна **на философские обобщения такого рода.**

Так что мы, скорее всего, имеем только  собственное представление о речи прачек и только собственное толкование вариантов, подходящих **по лексике, не более того.**  Просто вариант мытарь – палач лучше выражает противопоставление, которое главное в этой теме, но лексически он менее убедителен.

Теперь я так вижу эту проблему.

P.S.   **О народной этимологии**

Почему эта тема так огорчила меня, просто себя не узнаю!  Больше всего я люблю свободу и независимость в суждениях, а вчера чего испугалась?  **Как волк, не могла переступить красную ленточку, этот ярлык с надписью  «народная этимология»?** Да, меня вполне устаивает мое собственное мнение, даже если оно так называется!

Я знаю законы письма и уважаю эти законы. Я считаю, что мы достаточно **свободны,** даже находясь в рамках  существующих правил.  Поэтому здесь я и буду работать, если посчитаю это нужным. Но вот другие разделы  языка – не для меня (кроме стилистики и грамматики, разумеется).

И особенно **этимология**, где можно  только что-то пересказывать, но категорически запрещается думать, иначе это будет называться  – народной этимологией!  Вы еще не знаете, что это такое? **О, это особо опасный  вид  невежественного инакомыслия.**

Но вот  об авторах научной этимологии  я  не очень высокого мнения, читать их не собираюсь.  Рядом с Черных никто из них не стоял. Жаль, что у него словарь неполный (не успел закончить при жизни).

Чтобы сказать что-то новое о происхождении слов,  нужно иметь **талант, призвание, чувство языка и уникальные знания в области лингвистики**. Таких людей **единицы**, списка не составишь. Разумеется, вряд ли кто-нибудь из нас, кто читал словарь Черных или даже другой этимологический словарь, будет пробовать себя в этой области (другими словами, искать индоевропейские корни и общеславянские основы).  Подобные опыты действительно нельзя принимать всерьез и следует отнести к "народной этимологии".

Но фразеология – это немного другое. Фразеологический оборот –  это область **народного творчества**, обобщение жизненного опыта в образных реалиях. Здесь  надо более критично относиться   к высказываниям  профессиональных этимологов, а также  **к народному мнению не мешает прислушаться.** Считается, что народ  у нас «лаптем щи хлебает», но, с другой стороны, он  же смышлёный, смекалистый, находчивый. Почему бы его и не послушать!