# Почему старый русский фразеологизм" не нытьём, так катаньем" так часто искажают в написании и в произношении словом "мытьём"? При чём здесь "мытьё"?

Tags: фразеология

Почему старый русский фразеологизм "Не нытьём, так катаньем" так часто искажают в написании и в произношении словом "**м**ытьём", вместо "**н**ытьём"? При чём здесь "мытьё"?
Некоторые умудряются и "кАтаньем", с ударением на первый слог, заменить на "катАнием", с ударением на втором слоге. Глагол "кАтовать" - от существительного "кат" (тиран, палач, мучитель...)
Смысл фразеологизма: добиться своего всеми возможными способами, от слезливых уговоров до угроз и деспотических методов.
Удивительно, но исказители этой фразы вкладывают примерно тот же смысл. Причём, объясняют её происхождение прообразами способов стирки белья.
Зачем уродовать и так понятную родную речь?

Comment: Этот вопрос задавался многократно. В строку "Поиск по сайту "Русский язык" заносим слово "катаньем" и нам откроется (например): https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461885/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be

Comment: "а "нытьё" и "вытьё" - это уже варианты глуховатых и изобретательных ;-)" — https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/3348764.html Там тоже люди с детства знают, только "мытьём".

Answer (score 1):

> Не мытьем, так катаньем. Даль.
>
> А то другой сосед у нас в те поры завёлся, Комов Степан Никтополионыч.
> Замучил было отца совсем: не мытьём, так катаньем. Иван Тургенев.
> «Однодворец Овсянников», из цикла «Записки охотника»
>
> Не тут, так там; коль не мытьем удастся, так
> катаньем. Алексей Толстой. «Царь Федор Иоаннович» .

> Катанье белья — это старинный способ глажки: отжатую ткань наматывали
> на валик или скалку и раскатывали рубелем по плоской поверхности.
> Рубелем называли деревянную доску с ручкой на одном конце.

Подробнее [тут](https://www.culture.ru/s/vopros/ne-mytyem-tak-katanyem/).

> КАТОВАТЬ (стар.) — рубить мачту. Морской словарь 1949 г. скорее всего от слова cut - резать.

Тот самый валик для "катания":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: — Православные, в чём согрубил,  Всё простите, виновен не мало, // Кат за дело Степана казнит… – Гиляровский, «Стенька Разин»

Comment: Каторга - галера, кат назывался вал на галере, возможно. Почему кат это палач сказать не могу. Каторга. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/254358 . Кат https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/254222

Comment: Ка́торга. Это слово заимствовано из греческого, где katergon (или katerga во множественном числе) имело значение «галера» (любопытно, что именно такое значение и имело это слово в русском языке в начальный период после заимствования). Незавидна была доля рабов на галерах, это и дало основания для переосмысления слова до современного значения — «тяжелая подневольная работа».

Comment: Понятно, КАТ  и греческое ЕРГОН  наводит на мысль, КАТЕРГОН - казнь для гребцов ("ергонавтов"). Позже понятие перекочевало на сушу в виде КАТОРГИ?

Comment: "— Православные, в чём согрубил,  Всё простите, виновен не мало, // Кат за дело Степана казнит… – "(Гиляровский, «Стенька Разин» ). Здесь "КАТ" имеет значение "палач" Старое русское слово "катовать" происходит от этого слова со значением "казнить", косвенно - тиранить, издеваться, мучать... Есть ещё слово "КАТА" -плаха. Можно "Катовать" голову или руки-ноги... Можно мачту корабля.  Когда невоспитанное дитя просит у матери шоколадку оно сначала пользуется НЫТЬЁМ, потом криком, после КАТАНЬЕМ - колотит дуру-мать ручонками, кидается на пол. И "МЫТЬЁМ" не пользуется. "Не НЫТЬЁМ, так КАТАНЬЕМ".

Comment: @Георг ну это прекрасно, но значение можно и придумать. Ну есть такое что кат - это палач, но за этим все. шоколадок кстати не было на Руси, что просили у матери: брюкву, редьку, хрен? То есть если вы фантазируете, вы хоть делайте поправку на историзм нарратива.

Comment: Дело не в шоколадке и редьке, а в актуальности и яркости фразы во все времена. Здесь отображение желания достижения цели любым путём, от мягкого до жестокого. "МЫТЬЁ" придумали, видимо, слабослышащие из-за созвучия слов нытьё и мытьё. Но в начале было слово "нытьё", со школы помню...

Comment: Скорее всего вы так и слышали с детства, но это не тоже самое, что так было всегда. Понятие цели тоже современное, никогда такой такой подход в максиму не возводился, тем более с нытьём.

Comment: «Такая праведная поступка необходимо должна вести человека к благополучию; и хотя, несмотря на сие, неправые фортунины затеи принуждают иногда таких людей скончать живот свой прежде, нежели пользоваться заслуженным от них благополучием, однако со всем тем не должно унывать в следовании за добродетелью, а, напротив того, крепко держаться ее, по крайней мере для того, что она нам в других людях кажет себя любезною и неоцененною»  То есть наоборот "не унывать" нужно.

Comment: Буратино, замените слово КАТАНЬЕ словом ТИРАНИЯ и прочтите сначала с МЫТЬЁМ, а после - с НЫТЬЁМ. "Не мытьём, так тиранией" и "Не нытьём, так тиранией". Неужели не понятно, что МЫТЬЁ здесь неуместно?

Comment: Ну это забавно, но что это даёт? зачем это?) это похоже на современные мемы с заменой содежания на какие-то эмоциональные лозунги. Вот вы пишете, что цель, мол, а цель в чём?чего добивается-то кричаще-режущий сорванец?

Comment: Похоже, вы Буратино, жертва ЕГЭ? Моя цель: побудить задуматься над бредовостью некоторых искажённых мемов, произносимых, иногда даже, очень высокопоставленными особами, и слепым повторением их ошибок  другими, не менее уважаемыми людьми.

Comment: ЕГЭ я не сдавал, не знаю, жертва ли я ЕГЭ или нет. Пословицы и поговорки - это не мемы.

Comment: Это фразеологизм, в рассматриваемом нами случае.

Comment: пусть, и что с того?

Comment: "... Мне за Державу обидно"(к/ф "Белое солнце пустыни")

Comment: так, и что дальше? это ещё нытьё или уже катаньё?

Comment: Увы, нытьё... В наше время законно только нытьё. И то, не всякое.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю к теме стихотворение А.С. Пушкина.

**КАТОРГА.**  В XV-XVIII вв. — мореходное гребное судно, род галеры (в гребцы на эти суда ссылались осужденные на каторгу). Словарь редких и забытых слов. 2012

А.С. Пушкин  **Сказка "Царь увидел пред собою"** (Неоконченная).

Неоконченный отрывок из записей Пушкина считается одним из ранних вариантов "Сказки о золотом петушке".

```
  Царь увидел пред собою
  Столик с шахматной доскою.

  Вот на шахматную доску
  Рать солдатиков из воску
  Он расставил в стройный ряд.
  Грозно куколки сидят
  Подбоченясь на лошадках,
  В коленкоровых перчатках,
  В оперенных шишачках,
  С палашами на плечах.

 Тут лохань перед собою
 Приказал налить водою;
 Плавать он пустил по ней
 Тьму прекрасных кораблей,
 Барок, КАТАРОГ и шлюпок
 Из ореховых скорлупок —

 . . . . . . . . . .
 . . . . . . . . . .
 А прозрачные ветрильцы
 Будто бабочкины крильцы,
 А веревки..
```

Comment: Кстати, не по правилам. По правилам можно только ответы. Комментарии тоже нельзя. Поэтому не форум, на форумах можно. На форумах нет такой строгости и комментарии не удаляют. Характерная черта форумов — свобода действий!